# Alternate Email Address each time a form submits

Tags: php, forms, email, sequential, alternate

Hi Could someone please tell me if the following is possible please?

I have a small php contact form which sends the information collected on the form to a designated email address

$emailaddress=whatever@whatever.com

What I am trying to achieve is that every time the form sends data, it switches so it would do the following...

Customer sends data via submit to $emailaddress1=whatever@whatever.com

The next customer sends data it submits to $emailaddress2=whoever@whoever.com
The next customer sends data via submit to $emailaddress1=whatever@whatever.com again and so on.

Essentially every other send switches the email address to a different one to the last send.

Thanks in advance
Tilly

Comment: Sure its possible. Are you currently using anything for data parsistance (eg database, xml file etc)

Comment: Thank you for your response.No, the data just gets populated in an email and sent to the at the moment single recipient

Comment: Ok, well you will need to save the last used email somewhere. If there is no database used by the current site, it may be simpler to use a flat file. How frequently is this form submitted?

Comment: Hi, not very often, probably 30-40 times a week maximum

Comment: Ok, see Boermema's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved thanks to Boerema plus a few little tweaks of my own.

Basically I just changed the delete part till after the form was processed, sine when the form is displayed it was deleting or creating without submission.

So...

In the form itself the code is...

```
$filename = '/full/path/to/tempfile/sent.txt'; 
if (file_exists($filename)) { //
$recipients = 'number1emailaddress@test.com';
} else {
$recipients = 'number2emailaddress@test.com';
}
```

Then **after** the form has processed

```
$filename = '/path/to/your/tempfile/sent/sent.txt';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
unlink($filename); //delete the file
} else {
fopen($filename, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$filename); //implicitly creates file
}
```

This way the file is only deleted/created on an actual submission, which works perfectly

Many thanks Boerema

Answer (score 2):

From the discussion in your comments, I would say the best answer is to use a simple file to indicate whether you want to send the email to address 1 or address 2. If you are ever only going to have two addresses, you could even simply use the EXISTENCE of the file as the indicator.

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $toAddr = 'whatever@whatever.com';
    unlink($filename); //delete the file
} else {
    $toAddr = 'whoever@whoever.com';
    touch($filename); //create the file empty
}
```

If you have heavy usage, you may get an instance where two emails would go to one email at the same time, but it doesn't sound like that is a big issue.

If you need to have more than two addresses, then just write out to the file and read the value to determine where you want to send it instead of deleting and creating it.

Comment: hello, no success at the moment, I have this code.... `if (file_exists(sent/sent.txt)) {
    $recipients = 'whatever@whatever.com';
    unlink(sent/sent.txt); //delete the file
} else {
    $recipients = 'whoever@whoever.com';
    touch(sent/sent.txt); //create the file empty
}`
The "sent" folder is writable chmod 777 is this correct?

Comment: I assume you have quotes around your file path? Also, you may need to set the file path as `__DIR__ . 'sent/sent.txt'` in some server configurations. Have you gotten the file to actually right out to the location?

Comment: Hi Boerema, I have figured it all out now, slightly different to what you suggested, but many thanks for you guidance. Couldn't have done it without you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a counter to know which email to send to.

```
$counter = 0;

if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ){

    $counter++;

    if ( $counter % 2 == 0 ){

        $email = 'email@address.com';

    } else {

        $email = 'email2@address.com';

    }

}
```

This will put a different email at even and odds.

Comment: Hello, thank you, does this require that the file containing the code is writable?

Comment: This solution would only work if this script was somehow persisted, which I don't see how it could be. Instead of having the `$counter` initialized, you could just read it in from a file, but then you might as well use my solution.

Comment: This solution does not require any type of file to be saved or for the file it's on to be writable. I'm under the assumption PHP mail or some other mail script is being used to email out to the person filling out the contact form. Why create a file, read it, then send it just to simply find out which email to send to? If you have a config.inc.php with your email script, db connections, etc., then you don't need to create a file, simply let the form choose the email you're sending to by checking a counter and placing the correct variable for the email. Then again, that was my assumption.

Comment: But, yes, it would need to be persisted as the counter would reset with every form so a number would need to be kept in a DB in order for it to continue counting.